# extension issue of image while uploaded in database

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, phpmyadmin

I need help in my problem. I want to upload multiple images in my database. I am putting the path in my database and the images in a folder. The upload is working I think, but if I see the path in the database it looks like this:

```
projects/projects_past/benefits.pnh
```

The extension of the image should be `.png` Why I am taking this `.pnh`???

I am asking the user How many images you want to upload ? for example 3,
so I give him in the same php file three input type file to upload them. After submitting, there is a redirection to another php which I insert the images into the database.

The first php file has this code:

```
if($submit_num_images)
{
echo "<form action='img_projects.php?num_images=".$num_images."' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' name='form3' id='form3'>";
$temp_num = 0;
while($temp_num != $num_images){
    echo '<tr><td>Choose image number:&nbsp;'.$temp_num.'</td><td colspan="2"><input type="file" name="image[]" id="image[]" multiple /> </td></tr>';
    $temp_num++;
}
echo '<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td> Choose the Project that related to the images </td>
<td colspan="2">';
    $titles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM projects");
    echo '<select name="title_project">';
    $count = 0;
    while($values_titles = mysql_fetch_assoc($titles))        {
        echo'<option value="'.$values_titles['id_project'].'">"'.$values_titles['title'].'"</option>';
        $count++;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" name="img_insert" id="img_insert" value="1" /></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"> <input type="submit" name="submit_project_image" value="Submit the images of a project" id="submit_project" /></td></tr>';
}       
echo '</table>';
echo '</form>';
} // end insert 2

?>
```

This is the second php file:

```
for($i=0; $i<$num_images; $i++){
if($_FILES['image']['name'][$i] == "") {
//header('Location:controlpanel.php?insert=2&msg=0');   
}
else {
$pics.$j = "projects/projects_past/".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $pics.$j);
$j++;
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO img_projects (id_project,image) VALUES ("'.$title_project.'","'.$pics.$j.'") ') or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

I have a table for the multiple upload images image[]

Any help or suggestions, I would appreciate!

I have the right to write in my database

I am using *MyISAM*, *utf8 general_ci*

the field `image` in my table is *varchar(500)*

thanks for reading!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `$pics.$j` but it will not do what you expect, especially when you try to assign to it ( `$pics.$j = "projects/projects_past/".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];` ). Just use `$pics` by itself; the variable will be overwritten in every iteration of your for loop, so you don't need to try to make a new variable every time. If you do want to track the multiple `$pics` paths for use after the loop, that make $pics an array:

```
$pics = array();
$j = 0;

for($i=0; $i<$num_images; $i++){
if($_FILES['image']['name'][$i] == "") {
//header('Location:controlpanel.php?insert=2&msg=0');   
}
else {
$pics[$j] = "projects/projects_past/".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $pics[$j]);
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO img_projects (id_project,image) VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($title_project).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($pics[$j]).'") ') or die(mysql_error());

$j++;
}
}
```

I also added `mysql_real_escape_string()` for you around `$title_project` and the `$pics[$i]` path to protect from SQL injection attacks (sneaky SQL code that a hacker can send in the title_project or file name).